# HTML Change Input Text Color and Clear Value On Focus

Tags: html

I have an input text that I would like to contain default text as grey, then if it gains focus, clear the default text and change the text color to black. The clearing of the text works, but when I start typing the text remains grey instead of black. I have:

```html
<input class="TB_DEFAULT" type="text" id="txtValue" value="enter notice or order" style="color:lightgray" onchange="this.style='color:black'" onfocus="if(this.value=='enter notice or order') this.value='';" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `placeholder="enter notice or order"` instead?

Comment: You're looking for the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Yes, placeholder works for removing the text when it has focus, but I would like the placeholder text to be grey, but user entered text to be black. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a placeholder tag should do the trick without any javascript.

Try this:

```
<input class="TB_DEFAULT" type="text" id="txtValue" placeholder="enter notice or order"/>
```

Adding some CSS examples to help with styling of the placeholder text:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
color: red;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, placeholder works for removing the text when it has focus, but I would like the placeholder text to be grey, but user entered text to be black. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I just updated my answer with some CSS for placeholder text. @J.Cart

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtValue").css('color', '#cfcfcf');
  $("#txtValue").val('enter notice or order');

  $("#txtValue").on('focus', function() {
    $("#txtValue").css('color', '#000000');
    $("#txtValue").val('');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="TB_DEFAULT" type="text" id="txtValue">
```